# ImageMagick API increasing file size 10 times on adding a simple rectangle

Tags: c#, image, .net-core, imagemagick, tiff

I have been asked to draw a rectangle over tiff/pdf/png/jpg file of a given size at a given coordinates.

I am using ImageMagick (Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU ver 7.23.2.1) for it as it supports TIFF out of the box and using GhostScript it can support PDF.

Using the following code I can add rectangles to any page at a given coordinates.

```
        using var sourceMs = new MemoryStream(request.Bytes) { Position = 0 };

        using var images = new MagickImageCollection();
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        sourceMs.Position = 0;
        images.Read(sourceMs, new MagickReadSettings());
        foreach (var page in request.Pages)
        {
            foreach (var redaction in page.Redactions)
            {
                images[page.PageNumber].Draw(
                    new Drawables()
                        .FillColor(MagickColors.DarkGray)
                        .Rectangle(
                            redaction.XCoordinate,
                            redaction.YCoordinate,
                                redaction.Width,
                                    redaction.Height)
                );
            }
        }

        // I tried this first for reducing file size
        //foreach (var image in images)
        //{
        //    image.SetCompression(CompressionMethod.LosslessJPEG);
        //    image.Scale(new Percentage(50));
        //}

        images.Write(ms, GetFormat(request.MediaType));

        // new trick to reduce size but tiff is not supported.
        ms.Position = 0;
        var optimizer = new ImageOptimizer();
        optimizer.LosslessCompress(ms);

        ms.Position = 0;
        return ms.ToArray();
```

However once the rectangle is added - the final file size is 10 times larger than the original file which was fed to the above function.

I tried few things to reduce size by adding compression, scaling and optimiser but nothing worked. I am sure I must be missing something.

Thanks

Comment: If you start with an 8-bit image and add a rectangle with anti-aliasing, it adds lots of new colors from the blending of the anti-aliasing. So the result might be 24-bits. You should reset the output to an 8-bit version. With PNG you would use the prefix PNG8:your_output.png. With tiff, you would (in command line) add -type palette. Etc.

Comment: Nice tip; thanks. Any idea how I can I achieve the same using the API?

Comment: Sorry, I only code in command line. But you can ask on the ImageMagick GIT forum. https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick. The Magick.Net developer should be able to help you.

Comment: @fmw42 - I checked the bit depth and it was same before and after the image manipulation. it was 16. I have also posted this question on image magick github discussions page.

Comment: You can reduce the bit-depth using -depth 8. But I was talking about the color format of the input image. If it was 8-bit palette color, then adding something to the image can add more than 256 colors and thus cause the image to become 24-bit true color with millions of colors.